# What does this bit of MSDN documentation mean?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

The first parameter to the `EnumFontFamiliesEx` function, according to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is described as:

> *hdc [in]*
>   A handle to the device context from which to enumerate the fonts.

1. What exactly does it mean?
2. What does **device context** mean?
3. Why should a device context be related to fonts?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you read [the documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:msdn.microsoft.com+%22device+context%22)?

Comment: Regarding 2., why did you not search the documentation to see [what a device context is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183553(v=vs.85).aspx)? You should try some more research then come back with a better question.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I did see that. All everything has to say about device contexts are that it is just a bunch of information about a device like a display device, printer, etc. That just confused me further. I really do not see how fonts and device contexts are related. So, I thought maybe there was some other meaning to that word. Hence the question. By the way, I'm using this function to test if a particular font is installed in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question (3) is a legitimately difficult thing to find an explanation for, but the reason is simple enough:

Some devices provide their own font support. For example, a PostScript printer will allow you to use PostScript fonts. But those same fonts won't be usable when rendering on-screen, or to another printer without PostScript support. Another example would be that a plotter (which is a motorized pen) requires vector fonts with a fixed stroke thickness, so raster fonts can't be used with such a device.

If you're interested in device-specific font support, you'll want to know about the [`GetDeviceCaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks for that info! All I wanted to do was to enumerate a list of certain fonts installed in a system. I then noticed a hWnd parameter which confused me quite a bit. So in my case, that parameter is irrelevant; correct?

Comment: @Anish: I'm not sure where you're seeing a window handle... but the device context can't be "irrelevant", since it isn't optional.  You have to provide one in order to use `EnumFontFamiliesEx`.  If you don't care which device, then you might use a DC associated with the desktop window as a reasonable default.

Comment: I noticed it in the [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921543.aspx) function. Thank you for that tip about the desktop window. I guess I'll go with that. One last question. Suppose I have 2 fonts installed on a computer, A and B (i.e. in the Windows/Fonts directory). Now, will changing the device context while keeping all other parameters the same have any effect on the enumerated fonts (i.e. will they differ)?

Comment: @Anish: It depends on the format of the fonts.  I gave you two examples in my answer, and the `GetDeviceCaps` documentation lists a whole bunch more possible restrictions.  But if you're asking whether DCs from different windows on the same video card will have different fonts, then no there will be no difference.  But there may easily be differences between a video card DC and a printer DC.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has other articles on device context,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/about-device-contexts

> An application must inform GDI to load a particular device driver and,
>   once the driver is loaded, to prepare the device for drawing
>   operations (such as selecting a line color and width, a brush pattern
>   and color, a font typeface, a clipping region, and so on). These tasks
>   are accomplished by creating and maintaining a device context (DC). A
>   DC is a structure that defines a set of graphic objects and their
>   associated attributes, and the graphic modes that affect output. The
>   graphic objects include a pen for line drawing, a brush for painting
>   and filling, a bitmap for copying or scrolling parts of the screen, a
>   palette for defining the set of available colors, a region for
>   clipping and other operations, and a path for painting and drawing
>   operations. Unlike most of the structures, an application never has
>   direct access to the DC; instead, it operates on the structure
>   indirectly by calling various functions.

Obviously font is a kind of drawing.

Answer (score 1):

The windows API uses the concept of handles extensively. A handle is an integer value that you can use as a token to access an API resource. You can think of it as a kind of "this" pointer, although it is definitely not a pointer.

A device context is an object within the windows API that represents a something that you can  draw on or display graphics on. It might be a printer, a bitmap, or a screen, or some other context in which creating graphics makes sense. In Windows, fonts must be selected into device contexts before they can be used. In order to find out what fonts are currently available in any given device context, you can enumerate them. That's where EnumFontFamiliesEx comes in.